# How can I check if a date is valid in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I already have a function to validate my date. The problem is that I don't have the verification for February 30, for example. I think that maybe there's an easier native way to do this validation on Android. Can you help me?

My current validating function is:

```
fun isDateOfBirthValid(date: String): Boolean {
    if (date.length != 10) {
        return false
    }

    val day = date.substring(0, 2).toIntOrNull()
    val month = date.substring(3, 5).toIntOrNull()
    val year = date.substring(6, 10).toIntOrNull()

    if (day == null || month == null || year == null) {
        return false
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 12 || year < 1900) {
        return false
    }

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
    if (LocalDate.parse(date, formatter) > LocalDate.now()) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Yes. To make it easier, remove all manual checks and just only use the pattern-based check. That really is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying to parse the date is enough. If it throws an exception you know it is incorrect. Or when the parsed date doesn't match the input. So like this for example

```
fun isDateOfBirthValid(date: String): Boolean {
    try {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
        val localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter)
        if (!formatter.format(localDate).equals(date) || localDate > LocalDate.now()) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do it nearly exactly like this… I like the check for future dates of birth ^^ However, you could additionally involve the check for dates before 1900 OP has in his code.

Comment: @deHaar ah yeah. Somehow I missed he checked for that in the original post. By the way the check for future dates was already in the original too

Comment: Oh, I see… So we both missed a thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

object DateValidator {

    fun isDateValid(dateStr: String): Boolean {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
        sdf.isLenient = false // This ensures strict date validation

        return try {
            val date = sdf.parse(dateStr)
            // If the parsing succeeds, the date is valid
            true
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            // If an exception is caught, the date is not valid
            false
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
val inputDate = "2023-07-31"
val isValidDate = DateValidator.isDateValid(inputDate)
```

hope this helps

Comment: I have tried the solution above but this seems like a good and workable solution too, thanks for the reply